# code that generates an exam assessment report that includes the question IDs (as columns) and the answers (as their values)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need to write code that generates an exam assessment report (given the answers from multiple students and their attempts) that includes the question IDs (as columns) and the answers (as their values).
And i need note that a student (participant) can answer one or more questions in a single assessment and geo tag.

```
     /** Input data */
    val inputDf = Seq(
    (1, "Question1Text", "Yes", "abcde1", 0, List("x1", "y1")),
    (2, "Question2Text", "No", "abcde1", 0, List("x1", "y1")),
    (3, "Question3Text", "3", "abcde1", 0, List("x1", "y1")),
    (1, "Question1Text", "No", "abcde2", 0, List("x2", "y2")),
    (2, "Question2Text", "Yes", "abcde2", 0, List("x2", "y2"))
    ).toDF("Qid", "Question", "AnswerText", "ParticipantID", "Assessment", "GeoTag")
    println("Input:")
    inputDf.show(false)
```

My solution was:

```
     inputDf
    .groupBy($"ParticipantID")
    .pivot("Question")
    .agg(first($"ParticipantID"))
    .sort($"ParticipantID")
```

But this is what i got:

```
     Input:
     +---+-------------+----------+-------------+----------+--------+
     |Qid|Question     |AnswerText|ParticipantID|Assessment|GeoTag  |
     +---+-------------+----------+-------------+----------+--------+
     |1  |Question1Text|Yes       |abcde1       |0         |[x1, y1]|
     |2  |Question2Text|No        |abcde1       |0         |[x1, y1]|
     |3  |Question3Text|3         |abcde1       |0         |[x1, y1]|
     |1  |Question1Text|No        |abcde2       |0         |[x2, y2]|
     |2  |Question2Text|Yes       |abcde2       |0         |[x2, y2]|
     +---+-------------+----------+-------------+----------+--------+

     Expected:
     +-------------+----------+--------+-----+-----+-----+
     |ParticipantID|Assessment|GeoTag  |Qid_1|Qid_2|Qid_3|
     +-------------+----------+--------+-----+-----+-----+
     |abcde1       |0         |[x1, y1]|Yes  |No   |3    |
     |abcde2       |0         |[x2, y2]|No   |Yes  |null |
     +-------------+----------+--------+-----+-----+-----+

     Actual:
     +-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
     |ParticipantID|Question1Text|Question2Text|Question3Text|
     +-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
     |abcde1       |abcde1       |abcde1       |abcde1       |
     |abcde2       |abcde2       |abcde2       |null         |
     +-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
inputDf
  .groupBy($"ParticipantID",  $"Assessment", $"GeoTag")
  .pivot("Question")
  .agg(first($"AnswerText"))
  .sort($"ParticipantID")

  .show(false)
```

You can rename the column later as you want.

Output:

```
 +-------------+----------+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|ParticipantID|Assessment|GeoTag  |Question1Text|Question2Text|Question3Text|
+-------------+----------+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|abcde1       |0         |[x1, y1]|Yes          |No           |3            |
|abcde2       |0         |[x2, y2]|No           |Yes          |null         |
+-------------+----------+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is useful-

```scala
 /** Input data */
    val inputDf = Seq(
      (1, "Question1Text", "Yes", "abcde1", 0, List("x1", "y1")),
      (2, "Question2Text", "No", "abcde1", 0, List("x1", "y1")),
      (3, "Question3Text", "3", "abcde1", 0, List("x1", "y1")),
      (1, "Question1Text", "No", "abcde2", 0, List("x2", "y2")),
      (2, "Question2Text", "Yes", "abcde2", 0, List("x2", "y2"))
    ).toDF("Qid", "Question", "AnswerText", "ParticipantID", "Assessment", "GeoTag")
    println("Input:")
    inputDf.show(false)
    inputDf.printSchema()

 /**
      * Input:
      * +---+-------------+----------+-------------+----------+--------+
      * |Qid|Question     |AnswerText|ParticipantID|Assessment|GeoTag  |
      * +---+-------------+----------+-------------+----------+--------+
      * |1  |Question1Text|Yes       |abcde1       |0         |[x1, y1]|
      * |2  |Question2Text|No        |abcde1       |0         |[x1, y1]|
      * |3  |Question3Text|3         |abcde1       |0         |[x1, y1]|
      * |1  |Question1Text|No        |abcde2       |0         |[x2, y2]|
      * |2  |Question2Text|Yes       |abcde2       |0         |[x2, y2]|
      * +---+-------------+----------+-------------+----------+--------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- Qid: integer (nullable = false)
      * |-- Question: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- AnswerText: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- ParticipantID: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- Assessment: integer (nullable = false)
      * |-- GeoTag: array (nullable = true)
      * |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
      */

    inputDf
      .groupBy($"ParticipantID", $"Assessment", $"GeoTag")
      .pivot("Qid")
      .agg(
        first($"AnswerText").as("Q")
      )
      .orderBy($"ParticipantID")
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +-------------+----------+--------+---+---+----+
      * |ParticipantID|Assessment|GeoTag  |1  |2  |3   |
      * +-------------+----------+--------+---+---+----+
      * |abcde1       |0         |[x1, y1]|Yes|No |3   |
      * |abcde2       |0         |[x2, y2]|No |Yes|null|
      * +-------------+----------+--------+---+---+----+
      */
```